# Bash/grep: ignore lines over N characters

Tags: bash, find, grep

I have a find/grep command that i use to search my projects' codebase, thus:

```
find folder1 folder2 folderetc -print | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' | xargs grep -n "search-string"
```

Something that irritates me regularly is minified javascript & css files, which have everything packed into a single line (due to a probably misguided belief that removing newline characters will make downloading javascript files significantly quicker).  With these packed or minified files, there is always a non-packed version, which i want to see in my results.  I never want to see the packed version, as it just results in screens and screens of unreadable garbage.

There's no systematic way that i can tell grep to avoid minified or packed files, as there's no naming convention.  But it occurred to me that i could filter out results where the line is more than, say, 400 characters long.  Is there a way i can do this with grep (or something else?)

Comment: Also, take a look at [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com/) (or `ack-grep`). You can include a regex that specifies length and it will do the work of `find` and `xargs` for you. Plus it can be made to only search files of specified types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
$ echo foobar | awk 'length($0) < 7 && $0~/foo/'
foobar
```

Replace the `echo` with your find command and `foo` with the string to search for. Adjust the `7` to the length you want to filter by.

Comment: Thanks @dawud - i ended up keeping the search term via grep because i like the way it displays the line number, but tagging the awk onto the end:  `find folder1 folder2 folderetc -print | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' |xargs grep -n "search-term" | awk 'length($0) < 400'`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), which is basically grep optimized for programmers.  It ignores minified JS and CSS files, as well as any version control system files lying around in your directory.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson already suggested this in an earlier comment, too.  I've still not got round to looking at ack, but thanks for the prod.